# Use Module setting in Products

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have created a module called login_to_see_price. This module is used to hide the price of product if user is not not logged in. The module is working fine in admin part. But i am not getting any idea of implementing the settings of the module in all product. 
Module have form fields

```
status which can be 0=>disable 1=>enable
language (the sentence that is used instead of price) => Login to see price
```

I have kept these value in setting table.

So, when admin enable the setting i.e. status=1
then in froentend in place of product price i needed to display language=Login to see price .

How can i implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in each controller where you want to implement this feature. You can do like 
 `if($this->config->get('your_module_status')){
  login to see price and other code
 }else{
  default functionality
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Opencart Default provide this feature.

Edit setting / option tab under the Account Title there is Option Login Display Price. 
[image]